# Drupal 7 - Indexing Organic Groups tables to Apache Solr

Tags: solr, drupal-7, organic-groups

I've been struggling with this issue for all day long without finding any suitable answer. I'm working with a Drupal 7 installation hosted on Pantheon. I have some groups (from now on "Competitions") from which we want to see the members with the "Candidate" membership type (from the mysql table "og_membership"). But since there's going to be lots of participants in each competition, we want the search engine to be Apache Solr.

I've managed to retrieve a list with all the people from each single competition by the Nid from the URL and with a text field search through them, but i'm not able to filter again the members list by the user Organic Groups Membership Type (Candidate).

Is there any way that I can use to index that SQL table, for the Apache Solr to use it? Is there any other better way to do it?

Thank you very much in advance!